# How to make fast performance & Optimization in Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 Game + Memory Menegment?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing one game and would love to know the tips to get best memory management and performance optimization in Windows 7 Phone + Silverlight Coding.

My game also getting leg during the game play. Sometimes the game even gets paused for few seconds before it responds. Is is related to above or something else?

I am having Google Admob + Microsoft AD Sdk working so is above issue due to that?

I have used gc.collect() in my project but it does not seem to work properly. Is there anything i am missing?

I searched and tried to find official link or content that can guide me throgh best memory and performance management but not able to find so?

If anyone has any good link or idea, please do share along with above questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When coding with .Net, never call yourself GC.Collect(). For the optimizations, first you have to find what's consuming resources. You may try to use a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with understanding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967560(v=vs.92).aspx and then doing some profiling with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202934(v=vs.92).aspx